# How to use ajv with dependent json-schemas?

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I am tryng to make ajv work with two json-schemas, one dependent on the other.
Here an example (reduced) of my schemas:

**types.json**

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "$id": "http://a.site.org/schemas/types.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "gender":{"enum": ["male", "female"]}
    },
    "properties":{
        "gender":{"$ref": "#/definitions/gender"}
    }
}
```

**definitions.json**

```
{
"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"$id": "http://a.site.org/schemas/definitions.json",
"definitions": {
    "person":{
        "type":"object",
        "properties": {
            "username":{"type":"string"},
            "password": {"type":"string"},
            "name":{"type":"string"},
            "surname":{"type":"string"},
            "sex":{"$ref": "types.json#/properties/gender"},
            "email":{"type":"string", "format":"email"}
        },
        "required":["name", "surname", "sex", "email"]
    }
},
"type":"object",
"properties": {
    "person": {"$ref": "#/definitions/person"}
    }
}
```

From node, I use ajv like this:

```
import Ajv, {JSONSchemaType, DefinedError} from "ajv"
import {Gender} from "./types"
import {Person} from "./definitions";
const ajv = new Ajv()

const types : JSONSchemaType<Gender>= require("../types.json");
const PersonSchema : JSONSchemaType<Person> = require('../definitions.json').definitions.person;

const isPerson = ajv.addSchema(types).compile(PersonSchema);
const riccardo:Person={name: "Riccardo", surname: "surname", sex: "male", email: "email@gmail.com"};
const personValid = isPerson(riccardo);
if (!personValid) console.log(isPerson.errors)
```

The error I get is:

> Error: no schema with key or ref "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"

**UPDATE:**
If I delete the "$schema ..." from types.json, the error I get is:

> MissingRefError: can't resolve reference types.json#/definitions/gender from id #

I used this reference: https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/blob/master/docs/validation.md#modular-schemas

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 7, support for draft-04 has been removed.
If you want to use draft-04, you need to use version 6 of ajv.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to make things work given my example?

Comment: The error is because you're trying to use draft-04 of JSON Schema, which is no longer supported by ajv. If you want to continue to use draft-04, you need to downgrade to ajv version 6.

Comment: Ok, I tried to use draft-06 in my shema, now I have a different error, do you know how to solve?

Comment: You're now asking a different question. The old question is actually valuable and useful for people. I suggest you post your new question as a new question, then I can see about helping you further =]

Comment: Ok, I edited again the question and posted the previous content as answer, so that it is more clear what I changed to make it work

Comment: Nearly but not quite. For people facing the errors you had, my answer is the correct answer. You now have another problem, and so you should ask another question and accept the answer which solved the problem you initially presented. - As a new question, not as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of an answer below, the problem was with the draft version.
Here I post how I solved using a more recent draft of json-schema.

The files are now changed in this way:

**types.json**

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/types.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "gender":{"enum": ["male", "female"]}
    },
    "properties":{
        "gender":{"$ref": "#/definitions/gender"}
    }
}
```

**definition.json:**

```
{
    "$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/definitions.json",
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "person":{
            "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
            "$id": "http://asite.org/schemas/person.json",
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "username":{"type":"string"},
                "password": {"type":"string"},
                "name":{"type":"string"},
                "surname":{"type":"string"},
                "sex":{"$ref": "types.json#/definitions/gender"},
                "email":{"type":"string", "format":"email"}
            },
            "required":["name", "surname", "sex", "email"]
        }
    },
    "type":"object",
    "properties": {
        "person": {"$ref": "#/definitions/person"}
    }
}
```

Used in this way:

```
import Ajv, {JSONSchemaType, DefinedError} from "ajv"
import {Gender} from "./types"
import {Person} from "./definitions";
const ajv = new Ajv();
ajv.addMetaSchema(require("../node_modules/ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-06.json"))

const types = require("../types.json");
const PersonSchema : JSONSchemaType<Person> = require('../definitions.json').definitions.person;
const isPerson = ajv.addSchema(types).compile(PersonSchema);
const riccardo:Person={name: "Riccardo", surname: "surname", sex: "male", email: "email@gmail.com"};

const personValid = isPerson(riccardo);
if (!personValid) console.log(isPerson.errors)
```

Now different error arises, but deleting the "email" property it works, so it's a different matter:

> Error: unknown format "email" ignored in schema at path "#/properties/email"